# Sprint Not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have made a first person script in C#, with the mouse look in a separate script. However, in my movement script, the basic walk feature works, but the sprint function does not. After changes to the script, resulting in a fairly inefficient but ultimately same script, I have reached the conclusion that it is simply not detecting or using any input from the sprint key, which has been set up in the editor - although I may be wrong. The script is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 3.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;
public float runSpeed = 6f;
public float crouchSpeed = 3f;
Vector3 moveDirection;
void Update() {

    CharacterController controller = GetComponentInParent<CharacterController>();
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump")){
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }


    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetButton("Sprint")){
        controller.Move (moveDirection * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
        controller.Move (moveDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: This may not contribute to your current problem, but you may want to consider enclosing `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)` within a single set of brackets in your if condition for sprinting.

Comment: Adding brackets should solve your problem, Serlite is correct.

Comment: @Atra Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, do you mean simply `if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) && Input.GetButton("Sprint"))`? I tried this and it did not change the current situation, but I feel I misunderstood the solution.

Comment: That was indeed my suggestion, but your description of the problem doesn't seem to indicate that this was the main issue here. (But still implement it anyways, so that's one less problem to worry about.)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how you've set up the sprint key in the editor?

Comment: [SprintInput](http://tinypic.com/r/24w5a3m/8)

Comment: If you put Debug.Log(Input.GetButton("Sprint")) at the top of the update function does it ever return true?

Comment: It does indeed return true when it is pressed, and returns false when it is not, as intended.

Comment: I have now realised that, after using Debug.Log to show the current speed, it is unable to change the speed, and it stays at a constant 6 no matter what. I have removed the runSpeed from the controller.Move and made speed = runSpeed, and moveDirection *= speed, and this is still the case. However, I am unable to identify why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a boolean logic error: `&&` has precedence over `||`.

This line is faulty:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && Input.GetButton("Sprint"))
```

You should enclose the `||` conditions:

```
if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) && Input.GetButton("Sprint"))
```

Anyway, a better way would be to split the two parts:

```
if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    var realSpeed = Input.GetButton("Sprint") ? runSpeed : speed;
    controller.Move (moveDirection * realSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Are there any other problems? This does not seem to fix the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you should checkout operator precedence in C# (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The problem you're having is that the code will always go into the first condition of the if statement if W, S or A are pressed.

To fix it put brackets around the OR statements like this:

```
if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) && Input.GetButton("Sprint")){
    controller.Move (moveDirection * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
} 
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
    controller.Move (moveDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, whilst this probably fixes another problem that was not apparent to me, there seems to be another, as this does not seem to change my current problem. Are there any other, probably simpler, problems that I have missed? I can't seem to locate the problem, but the situation persists.

Comment: are you intending that the character move in different directions if W,S,D or A is pressed? With the code currently it will always move in the same direction regardless of which key is pressed

Comment: I am intending for the code to work as an ordinary first person script, and it does. it moves in all four directions depending on where the character is looking just as a normal first person script.